# payubiz integration is showing error in phonepe gradle

Tags: android

> **Failed to resolve: phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:0.1.3**

When I import module of payubiz its showing me error like this in this gradle:

```
compile 'com.payu.phonepe:phonepe-intent:1.0.0'
```

If I'm going to remove this gradle then the error also solved, but if i'm going to remove this , in the module have use of this, then its showing cannot fid symbol/package.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use implementation instead of compile.

Answer (score 1):

Add below URL in root project `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK"
        }
    }
```

[For More details visit this link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/PayU-PhonePe-Intent-SDK-Integration)